# loading an image from cifar-10 dataset

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I am using cifar-10 dataset for my training my classifier. I have downloaded the dataset and tried to display am image from the dataset. I have used the following code:

```
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
from  PIL import Image
import numpy as np

f = open('/home/jayanth/udacity/cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1', 'rb')

tupled_data= pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')

f.close()

img = tupled_data[b'data']

single_img = np.array(img[5])

single_img_reshaped = single_img.reshape(32,32,3)

plt.imshow(single_img_reshaped)
```

the description of data is as follows:
Each array stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue. The image is stored in row-major order, so that the first 32 entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of the image.

Is my implementation correct?

the above code gave me the following image:
[image]

Comment: Where did you get the dataset?

Comment: @frankyjuang  you can find it here:  http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~kriz/cifar.html

Comment: For posterity, I think this is the clearest piece of code I've found for CIFAR 10 because the code itself is very interpretable: https://www.quora.com/How-can-l-visualize-cifar-10-data-RGB-using-python-matplotlib

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used

```
single_img_reshaped = np.transpose(np.reshape(single_img,(3, 32,32)), (1,2,0))
```

to get the correct format in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python uses the default C-like indexing order (row-major order), it can be forced to work in column-major order:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# I assume you have loaded your data into x_train (see some tutorial)

data = x_train[0, :] # get a row data
data = np.reshape(data, (32,32,3), order='F' ) # Fortran-like indexing order
plt.imshow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
single_img_reshaped = single_img.reshape(3,32,32).transpose([1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.