# How to decide the np.reshape(image, (shape)) shape tuple based on the image structure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with CIFAR 10 dataset and had the exactly same issue while extracting a image from the dataset like in this post

[loading an image from cifar-10 dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104970/loading-an-image-from-cifar-10-dataset?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The images in this dataset has following structure -

> Each array stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain
>   the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024
>   the blue. The image is stored in row-major order, so that the first 32
>   entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of
>   the image.

For extracting a image I am doing (which I have done previously and worked)

> df_im = np.reshape(df['data'], (df['data'].shape[0], 32,32,3))

[Not working Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Airm4.png)

This reshape does not work as intended.

But this works -

> df_im = np.reshape(df['data'], (df['data'].shape[0], 3,32,32))

[Working Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHe0F.png)

**Why the latter worked in in this case but not the former one. And how to decide the np.reshape "shape" tuple based on the flattened array structure.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's recreate the data with smaller 'images':

```
In [68]: R = np.arange(4)
In [69]: G = np.arange(10,14)
In [70]: B = np.arange(20,24)
In [71]: rgb = np.hstack([R,G,B])
In [72]: rgb
Out[72]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

That looks like one of your images, doesn't it?  First N values are 'red', next N are 'green', etc>

Reshape to 2d:

```
In [73]: rgb.reshape(3,4)
Out[73]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

reshape to 3d:

```
In [74]: rgb.reshape(3,2,2)
Out[74]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13]],

       [[20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
```

'row major' means that the first dimension is outermost, and varies slowest.  Last dimension is the inner one.

```
In [75]: rgb.reshape(2,2,3)
Out[75]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]]])
```

`reshape` preserves the order of the data elements.  It just changes how they are viewed, divided, so to speak into planes, rows and columns.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, thanks for explaining this. Can you please clarify - When we are reshaping a 2d into 3d, in what sequence the elements of 2d array will be placed into different dimensions.

Comment: With rgb.reshape(2,2,3), I am assuming that my each channel is of shape (2,2). Now if I separate channel lets say red like this - `a=rgb.reshape(2,2,3)
print(a[:,:,0])`. Then it  should give me `[[0, 1],[2,3]]`. But it gives `[[ 0 3] [12 21]]`. I am confused with how numpy displays an array and how its actually structured.

Comment: I think I understand the behaviour now.

Comment: plus 1 for the explanation