# Loading dataset in UINT8 format- python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I was actually looking through the "load_data()" function in python that returns X_train, X_test, Y_train and Y_test as in [this](https://keras.io/datasets/) link. As you see it is for CIFAR10 and CIFAR100 dataset, that returns the above mentioned values as uint8 array.

I wanted to know is there some other function like this for loading datasets in our system locally ?

If so please help me with its usage and if not please suggest me some other alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`load_data()` is not a part of python but rather is defined in `keras.datasets.cifar10` module. To load `cifar` dataset (or any other dataset), there might be many methods depending upon how the dataset in packaged/formatted. Usually, the module [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can be used for loading/saving/manipulating table-like data.

For `cifar` data, here is another example: [loading an image from cifar-10 dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104970/loading-an-image-from-cifar-10-dataset)
Here the author is using the `pickle` module to unpack the dataset and then `PIL` and `numpy` modules to load and manipulate indivdual images.