# cifar100 dataset consists of repeated image?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I randomly browsed some images in [cifar100](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html), and found many images like this:
[image: sample image].

Anything went wrong? Or cifar100 indeed consist of such images?

Comment: can you please share [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code for loading and plotting these images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not load in the images correctly. Take a look at [loading an image from cifar-10 dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104970/loading-an-image-from-cifar-10-dataset) to see that others also have those problems. The correct way to reshape one of those cifar images is as follows:

```
single_img_reshaped = np.transpose(np.reshape(single_img,(3, 32,32)), (1,2,0))
```

Comment: yes, i reshape it as (32, 32, 3) which makes me get the wrong image. by the way, I'm curious why they don't store cifar as (32, 32, 3) which is more intuitive? (3, 32, 32) is somewhat annoying and I can't see any benefit of it.

Comment: It was the default order in Theano.

Comment: And CHW is in most places much faster and should be used in TensorFlow as well. Unfortunately, it isn't the default case.